# Is Queue the only option?

Tags: python-2.7, python-multiprocessing

I have two classes as follows:

```
q = multiprocessing.Queue()

class Class1(object):
    def __init__(self, device):
        self.device = device
        self.receiver = Class2(q).start()

class Class2(multiprocessing.Process):
    def __init__(self, queue):
        super(Class2, self).__init__()
        self.queue = queue

    def run(self):
        """This runs in a separate process."""

        self.consumer = KafkaConsumer("my_topic")
        while True:
            for msg in self.consumer:
                self.queue.put(msg)
```

The 2 part question is-

1. Can the instance of class Class1 get the message "msg" read from Kafka directly without being written to Queue? If so, how?
2. If using the Queue is the only way, is an infinite loop only the way for the instance to "get" the message from the queue?

Comment: sorry, what is `KafkaConsumer`? The whole question kind of relies on that info.

Comment: The consumer reads data from Kafka. Let that not be a distraction. Think of a task that is being executed inside a while loop.

Comment: it seems like you are asking if a queue is the only option for getting data from this `KafkaConsumer` object but not willing to share any details about it so there is no way I can know if there is another way of doing it.  You haven't given any information as to what your actual application is nor the facilities you are using nor what aspects you dislike about the Queue. If you can share more information then maybe we can help.

Comment: Sorry, I am not sure what information you are after. Regarding Kafka, you can see this - https://kafka.apache.org/. Regarding KafkaConsumer, its from the Python library to work with Kafka. What I am trying to find out is if the self object from Class1 be available in Class2 so that I probably won't need to write to the queue? Or, the only way to get data back to Class1 instance is via Queue?

Comment: ok assuming `Class2` has to be a seperate `Process` then the only way to safely transfer data between processes is via a queue (technically you could write custom code using `multiprocessing.Lock` but not recommended unless you already know how to) Is the issue that you want to have multiple `Class2` instances? You could create a queue for each.

Comment: it seems very odd to me that you would have the nested loop `while True: for .. in obj:` It would suggest that `self.consumer` creates new objects every time it is iterated over or you want an infinite loop of the same objects which is why I needed information about `KafkaConsumer`, the information I really need is what actually happens when you iterate over it?

Comment: The for loop grabs one message at a time from Kafka topic it is subscribed to. If there was no message, the for loop would terminate and so the while loop is needed.

Comment: What is a struggle for me is having to run another infinite loop on the instance side (or in Class1) to "get" the data from queue. That's why I am wondering if there is a better way.